# i am facing problem while going one page to another page using beautifulSoup in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Facing error while going one page to another page while crawling the data. Code is executed without error but the visited url should be updated from 1 to max_pages but is not for url like this:

https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart=00

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = input("Enter the URL : ")
max_pages = int(input("Enter the Maximum Number of Pages you want to Extract : "))

for i in range(1, max_pages+1):
    my_url = url[::-1].replace('1',str(i) ,1)[::-1]
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: `Facing error` please be more specific. No one wants to execute the code to understand the error.

Comment: I am unable to shift from one page to another page while crawling the data. Please tell me how to fix this line of code? my_url = url[::-1].replace('1',str(i) ,1)[::-1]

Comment: Please edit your post and give us the exact error message.

Comment: Please see it now.i have edit it.

Comment: ... i'm sorry, `while crawling the data` is not the exact error message raised when you execute your code.

Comment: Error is this my code is not working for page shift on the above website which already mentioned.

Comment: How couod i tell about the error because code is running successfully. But it is not increment the page number.

Comment: `But it is not increment the page number.` this is not obvious at all when we first read your question. We should not struggle trying to help you. I edited

Answer (score 0):

The error is here :

```
my_url = url[::-1].replace('1',str(i) ,1)[::-1]
```

You try to replace `1` with `str(i)` but there  is no `1` inside the url `https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart=00`so it cannot be updated.

Anyway I don't see any good solution for your issue here. If you let the user gives you any address he wants, you could have some url like this :

```
https://www.url1.com?n=1&p=1
```

where `p` is the page number and others like this

```
https://www.url11.com?p=1&n=1
https://www.url111.com?n=1&p=1
```

where this time `n` is the page number.

Good luck to find an automatic way to change the page number for all these urls.

If your parser is coded for yelp, I would do something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

user_id = input("Enter the YELP user id : ")
max_pages = int(input("Enter the Maximum Number of Pages you want to Extract : "))

url_base = "https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid={}".format(user_id)

for i in range(0, max_pages):
    page = "&rec_pagestart{:02d}".format(i*10)
    url = url_base + page
    print(url)
    #do parsing stuff
```

which parses 10 different pages :

```
Enter the YELP user id : _NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA
Enter the Maximum Number of Pages you want to Extract : 10
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart00
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart10
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart20
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart30
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart40
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart50
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart60
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart70
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart80
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=_NpJZ0q8KVI-d2YLL_VpCA&rec_pagestart90
```

Comment: Thank you so much its amazing. But when i do parsing it show some error.
c:\users\shani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:335: UserWarning: "https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=7IV3JXTXufasWNSkDEdrcQ&rec_pagestart40" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
  ' that document to Beautiful Soup.' % decoded_markup

Comment: i am doing parsing for yelp like this:        

for i in range(0, max_pages):
    page = "&rec_pagestart{:02d}".format(i*10)
    url = url_base + page
#     print(url)
    page_soup = soup(url, "html.parser")
    
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "review"})
    print(containers)